# SOLR: Just uploading the data files to new server instead of data import?

Tags: solr

I probably don't know much about how SOLR works internally, but as I was trying to replicate a SOLR server in another server, I first tried to copy the data files (data folder) to the new server, and see if that worked. Well it did worked...

I always thought I needed to run data import manually to setup the SOLR server, but apparently based on what I see I don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr replication **is** a copy operation of index files using HTTP transport method rather than file based copy.

The advantage of using the built in replication scheme is that you rid yourself of potential problems such as filesystem locks. You will also get propagation of `optimize` requests which might be beneficial for components which might depend on it, such as the spellcheckers `buildOnOptimize`. Also it holds up well in performance compared to e.g., `rsync`.